# What do these type values in brackets inside a js object mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
vCard {
  version: '4.0',
  data: {
    version: [String: '4.0'],
    n: [String: 'Gump;Forrest;;;'],
    fn: [String: 'Forrest Gump'],
    org: [String: 'Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.'],
    title: [String: 'Shrimp Man'],
    photo: { [String: 'http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif'] mediatype: 'image/gif' },
    tel: [
      { [String: 'tel:+11115551212'] type: [ 'work', 'voice' ], value: 'uri' },
      { [String: 'tel:+14045551212'] type: [ 'home', 'voice' ], value: 'uri' }
    ],
    adr: [
      { [String: ';;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America']
        type: 'work',
        label: '"100 Waters Edge\\nBaytown, LA 30314\\nUnited States of America"' },
      { [String: ';;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America']
        type: 'home',
        label: '"42 Plantation St.\\nBaytown, LA 30314\\nUnited States ofAmerica"' }
    ],
    email: [String: 'forrestgump@example.com'],
    rev: [String: '20080424T195243Z']
  }
}
```

I can't find any information on what the `[String: 'Gump;Forrest;;;']` means, how do I just access the value itself? Whenever I `console.log` it in node, I get

```
[String: 'Forrest Gump (Full Name)']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [the fine manual](https://github.com/jhermsmeier/node-vcf), I found that the way to get the value of the 'FN' property is:

```
let fullName = card.get('fn').valueOf();
```

Comment: That did it, but one more question, is why do [String: value] whenever you just plain console.log it?

Comment: @Cayle it's overloading the `toString()` property of the `card` object and showing a "prettyfied" version of it (which isn't a valid JS object, but I don't think it's intended as such).

Comment: Weird, what's the advantage to doing it like that?

Comment: @Cayle perhaps to aid in debugging (showing the type of each property), or just to make it more readable for humans. There are no rules about the output of `console.log()` being valid JS =D (although it would have been nice if the developer also overloaderd `toJSON` so you'd be able to get proper JSON from it).